# alBufferData() sets AL_INVALID_OPERATION when using buffer ID obtained from alSourceUnqueueBuffers()

Tags: macos, audio, game-engine, openal

I am trying to stream audio data from disk using OpenAL's buffer queueing mechanism. I load and enqueue 4 buffers, start the source playing, and check in a regular intervals to refresh the queue. Everything looks like it's going splendidly, up until the first time I try to load data into a recycled buffer I got from alSourceUnqueueBuffers(). In this situation, alBufferData() always sets AL_INVALID_OPERATION, which according to [the official v1.1 spec](http://www.openal.org/documentation/openal-1.1-specification.pdf), it doesn't seem like it should be able to do.

I have searched extensively on Google and StackOverflow, and can't seem to find any reason why this would happen. The closest thing I found was someone with [a possibly-related issue](http://openal.996291.n3.nabble.com/Detach-buffer-issue-td5157.html) in an archived forum post, but details are few and responses are null. There was also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990701/why-would-alsourceunqueuebuffers-fail-with-invalid-operation) with slightly different circumstances, but the only answer's suggestion does not help.

Possibly helpful: I know my context and device are configured correctly, because loading small wav files completely into a single buffer and playing them works fine. Through experimentation, I've also found that queueing 2 buffers, starting the source playing, and immediately loading and enqueueing the other two buffers throws no errors; it's only when I've unqueued a processed buffer that I run into trouble.

The relevant code:

```
static constexpr int MAX_BUFFER_COUNT = 4;

#define alCall(funcCall) {funcCall; SoundyOutport::CheckError(__FILE__, __LINE__, #funcCall) ? abort() : ((void)0); }

bool SoundyOutport::CheckError(const string &pFile, int pLine, const string &pfunc)
{
    ALenum tErrCode = alGetError();
    if(tErrCode != 0)
    {
        auto tMsg = alGetString(tErrCode);
        Log::e(ro::TAG) << tMsg << " at " << pFile << "(" << pLine << "):\n"
                        << "\tAL call " << pfunc << " failed." << end;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void SoundyOutport::EnqueueBuffer(const float* pData, int pFrames)
{
    static int called = 0;
    ++called;

    ALint tState;
    alCall(alGetSourcei(mSourceId, AL_SOURCE_TYPE, &tState));
    if(tState == AL_STATIC)
    {
        Stop();
//      alCall(alSourcei(mSourceId, AL_BUFFER, NULL));
    }

    ALuint tBufId = AL_NONE;
    int tQueuedBuffers = QueuedUpBuffers();
    int tReady = ProcessedBuffers();
    if(tQueuedBuffers < MAX_BUFFER_COUNT)
    {
        tBufId = mBufferIds[tQueuedBuffers];
    }
    else if(tReady > 0)
    {
        // the fifth time through, this code gets hit
        alCall(alSourceUnqueueBuffers(mSourceId, 1, &tBufId));

        // debug code: make sure these values go down by one
        tQueuedBuffers = QueuedUpBuffers();
        tReady = ProcessedBuffers();
    }
    else
    {
        return; // no update needed yet.
    }

    void* tConverted = convert(pData, pFrames);

    // the fifth time through, we get AL_INVALID_OPERATION, and call abort()
    alCall(alBufferData(tBufId, mFormat, tConverted, pFrames * mBitdepth/8, mSampleRate));

    alCall(alSourceQueueBuffers(mSourceId, 1, &mBufferId));
    if(mBitdepth == BITDEPTH_8)
    {
        delete (uint8_t*)tConverted;
    }
    else // if(mBitdepth == BITDEPTH_16)
    {
        delete (uint16_t*)tConverted;
    }
}

void SoundyOutport::PlayBufferedStream()
{
    if(!StreamingMode() || !QueuedUpBuffers())
    {
        Log::w(ro::TAG) << "Attempted to play an unbuffered stream" << end;
        return;
    }

    alCall(alSourcei(mSourceId, AL_LOOPING, AL_FALSE)); // never loop streams
    alCall(alSourcePlay(mSourceId));
}

int SoundyOutport::QueuedUpBuffers()
{
    int tCount = 0;
    alCall(alGetSourcei(mSourceId, AL_BUFFERS_QUEUED, &tCount));
    return tCount;
}

int SoundyOutport::ProcessedBuffers()
{
    int tCount = 0;
    alCall(alGetSourcei(mSourceId, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, &tCount));
    return tCount;
}

void SoundyOutport::Stop()
{
    if(Playing())
    {
        alCall(alSourceStop(mSourceId));
    }

    int tBuffers;
    alCall(alGetSourcei(mSourceId, AL_BUFFERS_QUEUED, &tBuffers));
    if(tBuffers)
    {
        ALuint tDummy[tBuffers];
        alCall(alSourceUnqueueBuffers(mSourceId, tBuffers, tDummy));
    }
    alCall(alSourcei(mSourceId, AL_BUFFER, AL_NONE));
}

bool SoundyOutport::Playing()
{
    ALint tPlaying;
    alCall(alGetSourcei(mSourceId, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &tPlaying));
    return tPlaying == AL_PLAYING;
}

bool SoundyOutport::StreamingMode()
{
    ALint tState;
    alCall(alGetSourcei(mSourceId, AL_SOURCE_TYPE, &tState));
    return tState == AL_STREAMING;
}

bool SoundyOutport::StaticMode()
{
    ALint tState;
    alCall(alGetSourcei(mSourceId, AL_SOURCE_TYPE, &tState));
    return tState == AL_STATIC;
}
```

And here's an annotated screen cap of what I see in my debugger when I hit the error:

[image: Annotated view of debugger contents]

I've tried a bunch of little tweaks and variations, and the result is always the same. I've wasted too many days trying to fix this. Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you trying to fill buffer with data, when the buffer is still queued to the source.

Also this code is wrong.

```
if(tQueuedBuffers < MAX_BUFFER_COUNT)
{
    tBufId = mBufferIds[tQueuedBuffers];
}
else if(tReady > 0)
{
    // the fifth time through, this code gets hit
    alCall(alSourceUnqueueBuffers(mSourceId, 1, &tBufId));

    // debug code: make sure these values go down by one
    tQueuedBuffers = QueuedUpBuffers();
    tReady = ProcessedBuffers();
}
else
{
    return; // no update needed yet.
}
```

You can fill buffer with data only if it unqueued from source. But your first **if** block gets **tBufId** that queued to the source. Rewrite code like so

```
if(tReady > 0)
{
    // the fifth time through, this code gets hit
    alCall(alSourceUnqueueBuffers(mSourceId, 1, &tBufId));

    // debug code: make sure these values go down by one
    tQueuedBuffers = QueuedUpBuffers();
    tReady = ProcessedBuffers();
}
else
{
    return; // no update needed yet.
}
```

Comment: I actually switched to SDL Mixer a long time ago, when no one seemed to know what might be up with my AL code. If anyone can chime in to verify this answer, I will be happy to accept it.